# How to sum the three values using recursion - Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

*Write a function that returns the sum of all nodes, including root*

```
var nodes = {
  value: 7,
  left: { value: 1, left: null, right: null },
  right: { value: 4, left: null, right: null }
};
```

Considering this, result should be equal to 12.

```
sumTheTreeValues = root => {
  console.log(root.value);
  if (root.left != null) {
    sumTheTreeValues(root.left);
  }
  if (root.right != null) {
    sumTheTreeValues(root.right);
  }
};
```

If this code will log

```
7
1
4
```

How to return the sum of these numbers without having to pass new parameter ?

Comment: Start by trying to `return` a value instead of logging it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the left and right nodes value to the current value and return:

```js
var nodes = {
  value: 7,
  left: { value: 1, left: null, right: null },
  right: { value: 4, left: null, right: null }
};

sumTheTreeValues = root => {
  let value = root.value;

  if (root.left != null) {
    value += sumTheTreeValues(root.left);
  }
  if (root.right != null) {
    value += sumTheTreeValues(root.right);
  }
  
  return value;
};

console.log(sumTheTreeValues(nodes));
```

You can also shorten it up a bit because `null` is automatically casted to 0 when added to a number:

```js
var nodes = {
  value: 7,
  left: { value: 1, left: null, right: null },
  right: { value: 4, left: null, right: null }
};

sumTheTreeValues = root => root.value + 
  (root.left && sumTheTreeValues(root.left)) + 
  (root.right && sumTheTreeValues(root.right));

console.log(sumTheTreeValues(nodes));
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to wrap your function inside another:

```
 function sum(root) {
    var result = 0;
    var sumTheTreeValues = root => {
       result += root.value
       if (root.left != null) {
          sumTheTreeValues(root.left);
        }
        if (root.right != null) {
           sumTheTreeValues(root.right);
        }
     };
     sumTheValues(root)
     return result;
 }
```